# Updating a column in one table with a value in another table

Tags: mysql

At the end of each day I need to set yesterdays price = current price so that the following day I can calculate a change in price. I thought I could do this:

```
UPDATE i
SET i.yesterday_price = p.price
FROM instruments i
JOIN prices p ON i.instrument_id = p.instrument_id;
```

but I get a deadlock error. I'm sure this is easy but a thorough google search does not yield an answer that I can get to work with MySQL.